# In XSLT, is it possible to insert an element before the children with IDs?

Tags: xslt

I have a special case. In an xml document, I want to insert a specific element just before each child with ID. Is that possible?

I can do this without using xsl:copy of the node before which the new element is added.

### XML DOCUMENT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <ul>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id='123'>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
    </ul>
</books>
```

### expected result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
    <ul>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
    </ul>
    <anchor id="123"/>
    <ul id='123'>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
        <li>book name</li>
    </ul>
</books>
```

Can I do this without using ? The elements with id will have separate templates. If I use xsl:copy, the element specific templates won't be applied. Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"The elements with id will have separate templates."* Why don't you show us what you have so far, so we can add your requirement to it.

Answer (score 1):

The result you show can be easily achieved using:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[@id]">
    <anchor id="{@id}"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you have specific templates for processing other elements, you can add them and they will be applied.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I showed a very simplified problem. In my actual XML, it copies the original elements and it does not apply other templates. For example, there is a template to change "ul" to list, the list is not applied. I may not be able to copy all XSLTs here because I am dealing with DITA.

Comment: @Antony: You should be able to adapt this answer to your unposted code.  Next time, include a [mcve] in your question showing your attempt, and include sufficiently representative XML so that you most effectively leverage answerers' time.

Comment: @Antony Please edit your question and show (at least) the template you have mentioned. Also state whether your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or not.